# Symfony 3.3 Form is returning NULL for one field

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to get INSERT values from a form into DB, one of my form fields is brand_id which is returning NULL upon submission.

There are two entities having Many to One relationship

**Brand** 
id 
name

**Model**

id

brand_id (FK)

name

image_url

comment

All fields return a value but the brand_id returns NULL

Code and Entitys are as follows:

brand Entity:

```
<?php
// src/coreBundle/Entity/Brand.php
namespace coreBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use coreBundle\Entity\Model;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
*@ORM\Entity
*@ORM\Table(name="brand")
*/
class brand
{


    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
public $id;

    /**
    *@ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="model", mappedBy="brands")
     */
    protected $models;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->models = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return brand
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }



    /**
     * Add model
     *
     * @param \coreBundle\Entity\model $model
     *
     * @return brand
     */
    public function addModel(\coreBundle\Entity\model $model)
    {
        $this->models[] = $model;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove model
     *
     * @param \coreBundle\Entity\model $model
     */
    public function removeModel(\coreBundle\Entity\model $model)
    {
        $this->models->removeElement($model);
    }

    /**
     * Get models
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getModels()
    {
        return $this->models;
    }
}
```

model Entity :

```
<?php
// src/coreBundle/Entity/Model.php
namespace coreBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use coreBundle\Entity\Brand;

/**
*@ORM\Entity
*@ORM\Table(name="model")
*/
class model
{

/**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

/**
    *@ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    public $brand_id;


    /**
    *@ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    *@ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
    */
    private $image_url;

    /**
    *@ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
    */
    private $comment;

/**
    *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="brand", inversedBy="models")
    *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $brands;

/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="model_item", mappedBy="models")
     */
    private $model_items;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set brandId
     *
     * @param integer $brandId
     *
     * @return model
     */
    public function setBrandId($brandId)
    {
        $this->brand_id = $brandId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get brandId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBrandId()
    {
        return $this->brand_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return model
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set imageUrl
     *
     * @param string $imageUrl
     *
     * @return model
     */
    public function setImageUrl($imageUrl)
    {
        $this->image_url = $imageUrl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imageUrl
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageUrl()
    {
        return $this->image_url;
    }

    /**
     * Set comment
     *
     * @param string $comment
     *
     * @return model
     */
    public function setComment($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get comment
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }



    /**
     * Set brands
     *
     * @param \coreBundle\Entity\brand $brands
     *
     * @return model
     */
    public function setBrands(\coreBundle\Entity\brand $brands = null)
    {
        $this->brands = $brands;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get brands
     *
     * @return \coreBundle\Entity\brand
     */
    public function getBrands()
    {
        return $this->brands;
    }


}
```

My Controller Code:

```
public function newModelAction(Request $request)
    {
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('coreBundle:brand')
        ->findAll();


        if (!$product) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No product found for id '.$productId
                );
        }

        $model = new model();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($model)
        ->add('brand_id',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Brand Id'))
        ->add('name',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Model Name'))
        ->add('comment',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Comments'))
        ->add('image_url',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Image URL'))
        ->add('save',SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'Add Model'))
        ->getForm();


        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($model);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->render('coreBundle:layouts:newItem.html.twig',
                array('form'=>$form->createView(),));
        }


        // ... do something, like pass the $product object into a template
        return $this->render('coreBundle:layouts:newModel.html.twig',
            array('form'=>$form->createView(),));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove this:

```
   *@ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
   public $brand_id;
```

Because you have already the field for brands in this point:

```
    /**
    *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="brand", inversedBy="models")
    *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $brands;
```

You need also to remove getter and seeter of brandId and remove brand_id from the form and adding this for example:

```
       ->add('brand', EntityType::class, array(
            // query choices from this entity
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Brand',
        ))
```

Comment: Then it is giving errros on Getter and Setter methods

Comment: You need to remove brandId getter and setter and edit your form removing brand_id and add Brand

Comment: Removed, Getter and Setter and brand_id from model entity, Now where should I edit in the form, any hint? I tried following 
->add('brands',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Brand Id')) 
instead of 
->add('brand_id',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Brand Id'))

It is giving exception of : 
Expected argument of type "coreBundle\Entity\brand", "string" given
Any Idea?

Comment: I have update the answer with a solution, but I advise you to check into symfony form builder documentation

Comment: Thanks Alot, It worked finally, That means the relation based column (brand_id) does not need to be present in the entity. Accepted your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/**
*@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="brand")
*@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
protected $brands;
```